# I have to make sum of values using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table having date and amount column, I have to make the some of them monthly, so how can I do it.

Please refer image for database table:

[image]

Actually I wanted the output as 
in this month this much is the total, e.g if we have 5 entries in the month of Jan then I wanted the sum of all the 5 entries in the month of Jan, how can I do it?

Comment: attach your image in your question.

Comment: @RaviHirani http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSMdL.png image link

Comment: @1000111 actually i m not getting from where to start, i was thinking that i should get month from date and get the data from database related to that month and then calculate it.

Comment: you can do it using `sum` and `groupby`..

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum(total_amt)
from table_name 
group by month(paydate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(total_amt) as TotalAmount 
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATE(paydate) >= '2016-01-01' 
ND DATE(paydate) <= '2016-01-31'
```

This would give you back one row containing the total amount of january 2016.

2nd method:

```
SELECT SUM(total_amt) as TotalAmount
FROM table_name group by month(paydate)
```

This would give you back a row for each month with the total amount.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your 'paydate' field uses `date` data type,then you can use

```
SELECT SUM(total_amt) AS Sum FROM `Table_Name` GROUP BY MONTH(paydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations is use the function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) of php to obtain month of the date from the timestamp with:

```
$month = date_parse($date_parse)['month'];  // 1-12
```

Example: Assuming that `$query` has the database result with the rows containing the total amount and the payday, you could make:

```
$months_payments = array();
$current_month = '';
$payments_arr = array();
foreach ($query as $row){
       $pay_month = date_parse($row['payday'])['month'];

       if(strcmp($current_month, $pay_month)) != 0){
            $months_payments[$current_month]=$payments_arr;
            $current_month = $pay_month;
            $payments_arr = array();
        }

            $payments_arr.push($row['total_amt'])
     }
// To add the last month
$months_payments[$current_month]=$payments_arr;
$current_month = $pay_month;
```

After this sorting you should just need to sum the elements in each month array.  If you want to also differentiate for year, you will need to adapt the code.

Answer (score -2):

select all rows where date start in march...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE paydate LIKE '2016-03%");'
```

then echo the count it in your page...

```
echo "March entries: " . mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Treating dates like strings is pretty abusive. The `BETWEEN` operator is a better fit here, and as a bonus can be indexed so it doesn't melt down and kill your database.